# search implementation for virtual scroll

Tags: html, angularjs, scroll, datagrid, scrollbar

I have no code to produce for this question, it's a research.
I work with angularjs and I want to create a specific data grid.
This datagrid can display a large data (over 1 million). So I get data by bundle. 
My problem is I don't want page selector or infinite scroll, but I want a virtual scroll. A simple solution is to calculate the height of the scrollbar depends on the total rows multiply by row height, and it's works. But recently I have a new challenge : Row height depends of data and i can't defined a "standard" row heigth to calculate scroll height.

I search on internet but the problem seems to be solve only with page selector. So have you got any ideas to achieve this goal ? or any reference, implementation to based my refection ?

Thank's for your help and I hope my question is clear.

PS: No idea ?

Comment: Also check out this Observable-based virtual scroll implementation: https://github.com/dinony/od-virtualscroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure about ag-grid, but kendo grid would serve your purpose. 
Below is a link for loading more data using virtual scroll in kendo

local data - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-local-data

remote data - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data .

HTML tree grid is also good, checkout this 
http://htmltreegrid.com/Home/Demo
Performance wise both seems to be similar. HTML tree grid also have grids for differents purpose. But More customization of this grid looses the performance

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to define standard row height... you can measure row height dynamically..

HTML TABLE:

```
<input type="button" onclick="rowHeights();" value="Row Heights">
    <table id="rowHeight" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
               Column One<br />
               Big Column
            </td>

            <td>
               Column Two
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               Second row column 1
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function rowHeights() {
        var tbl = document.getElementById('rowHeight').rows;
        alert("First Row Height: " + tbl[0].offsetHeight);
        alert("Second Row Height: " + tbl[1].offsetHeight);
        //all row height
        var allrowHeight = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < tbl.length; i++) {
            allrowHeight += tbl[i].offsetHeight;
        }
        alert("Total Row Height: " + allrowHeight);
    }
```

I hope this will help you. JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1Luxb5a/

Comment: Unfortunatly, it's not the expected. I don't have all rows in DOM but just a little part (maybe 15/a lot of). And I need to simulate the scroll height as if all rows are displayed. Before I get row height of the first row and I based my calcul on it (rowHeight * totalRow) --> to have the number of pixel needed to display all data. This gave me a solution to simulate scroll height and implement a virtual scroll. But now row height can be different and I can't know the height of a row that isn't displayed. Do you understand my problem ?

Comment: if i ain't wrong, you need to calculate rowheight as well as scrollheight before appearing data into table. but you don't know the rowheight because data is dynamic. you want to calculate rowHeight of data before it appearing on view. Am I right?

Comment: if my assumption is right, you can do it with easiest way by keeping table hidden and measure the rowheight and get the pixel of your data and then simulate it to scrollheight.

Comment: The goal is to calculate the scroll height to simulate all data are present (if row count is 100000 i do have a little scroll, but if there is only 40 elements the scroll must be big. But at t time, I have a little part of data and this grows on scroll). Before I do that to calculate the first row height and multiply it by total row count (gave me a value in pixel that represent the scroll height). But now row height can't be based on the first row. My only solution is to calculate an average of row height based on displayed data. And want to know if there is another solution or a best way

Answer (score 0):

Silvinus, take a look on this concept:

**Virtual Paging / Infinite Scrolling**

> Virtual paging allows the grid to lazy load rows from the server
>   depending on what the scroll position is of the grid.
>
> If the grid knows how many pages in total at the start, the scroll
>   will be sized to match the entire data set despite the data set not
>   loaded from the server.
>
> If the grid does not know how many pages at the start, the scroll will
>   extend automatically until the last row is reached. This feature is
>   known in other grids as infinite scrolling.

Note: Pagination and Virtual Paging are different solutions to the same problem. It is not possible to apply both at the same time.

**Example:**
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-virtual-paging/virtualPaging.html

**Reference:** 
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-virtual-paging/

Comment: I know the concept of infinite scrolling. but the feature isn't the expected. We don't want a scroll which back to middle when you arrived at the end.
Thank's, but I'm put out.... my problem seem's not to be 'standard' or unresolvable

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate it approximately. Either estimate average height of row, if heights of rows are similar, or on backend, during saving record, calculate approximately height of rows and save it in the database (for instance based on text length). And then when you will load the data, you can sum all heights, and get it from server.